# Azure Worker Role + Ninject + Quartz

Tags: azure, ninject, quartz-scheduler, azure-worker-roles, ninject-extensions

I'm building a background process based on existing "Core" code (meaning there is a .Core project) which I am required to use.

The core code is based on Ninject. So I use the [Ninject.Extensions.Azure](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Azure).

Also the core I'm building is some sort of background processing that has to do with scheduling and for which I need Quartz. Therefore I installed [Ninject.Extensions.Quartz](https://github.com/dtinteractive/Ninject.Extensions.Quartz)

Now my problem is that Quartz will never create an instance of my job (regardless of a parameterless constructor).

Looking at the created Scheduler, it does not look like it returns the one from the Quart Extensions but I can't find out why.

Here is my Role Entry Point:

```csharp
public class WorkerRole : NinjectRoleEntryPoint
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private readonly ManualResetEvent runCompleteEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    private IScheduler scheduler;
    private IKernel kernel;
    public override void Run()
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("Company.Services.Report is running");

        try
        {
            RunAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token).Wait();
        }
        finally
        {
            runCompleteEvent.Set();
        }

    }

    protected override bool OnRoleStarted()
    {
        // Set the maximum number of concurrent connections
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;

        bool result = base.OnRoleStarted();

        Trace.TraceInformation("Company.Services.Report has been started");
        ConfigureScheduller();

        return result;
    }

    protected override void OnRoleStopped()
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("Company.Services.Report is stopping");

        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        runCompleteEvent.WaitOne();

        base.OnRoleStopped();

        Trace.TraceInformation("Company.Services.Report has stopped");
    }

    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(new CoreModule());
        return kernel;
    }

    private static async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("Working");
            await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
    private void ConfigureScheduller()
    {
        scheduler = kernel.Get<IScheduler>();

        // define the job and tie it to our WorkerJob class
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<ReportProcessorJob>().Build();

        // Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 12 hours
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .StartNow() //.WithCronSchedule("0 0 12 * * ?") //TODO: set good schedule start
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                .WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
                .RepeatForever())
            .Build();

        // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

        scheduler.Start();
    }

}
```

I'm not including the job as it only Traces info to the console for debug purposes.

Do you see anything wrong in there?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem!

Reason for the issue was that Ninject could not find the implementation of some needed interfaces. Sadly it was not saying anything, just not working...

In case it helps somebody, here is how I found it out:

1. In Visual Studio go to Debug -> Exceptions
2. Check the "Throw" for Common Language Runtime Exceptions

Then when you debug,it will show you the actual exception with a very clear message saying that it could not resolve IFoo.

HTH

Comment: that means someone (something in your application) swallowed the exception. You probably should do something to make them clearly visible for the developer. It *could* also be that Ninject.Extensions.Quartz or Ninject.Extensions.Azure are swallowing the exception. If that would be the case one should change that, though.

Comment: I've checked the code of both extensions and both do not catch exceptions without rethrowing them. Ninject.Extensions.Azure is a bit fishy (smelly) though because it has a "catch all" with a rethrow [here](https://github.com/dtinteractive/Ninject.Extensions.Quartz/blob/81bebfaf3aebb2cdb10b8b9176b3045e81fd0d88/Source/Ninject.Extensions.Quartz/NinjectJobFactory.cs#L57)

Comment: Indeed, could not agree more but I have no clue why. Might be Ninject or Quartz swallowing the exception rather that breaking clearly. Actually the worker role itself was working fine as Trace.TraceInformation("Working") was actually shown every second...

Comment: I've never experienced ninject to swallow exceptions *and* i've just checked Ninject.Extensions.Quartz and Ninject.Extensions.Azure that they don't do so. So it's either a swallowing `catch` in your code or you just done handle `UnobservedTaskException` / `AppDomain.UnhandledException` or something like that. From .net 4.5 on unobserved task exceptions don't lead to termination of the application so it's entirely possible you'll only see the side effects, never the exception.

Comment: I actually looked at the code of the Azure one and I'm not sure I'll keep it. Looking at what it does, I could do that myself I think.

Comment: Ninject.Extensions.Quartz can probably easily be written oneself as well. If used Quartz with ninject before (without the extension) and it's not that big a thing.